# What is XCB Error Code 3?

Tags: sway, xcb

Checking `journalctl /usr/bin/sway` I see lots of errors like this

```
[xwayland/xwm.c:1286] xcb error: op 18:0, code 3, sequence 42593, value 4194450
```

What do they mean, is there any reason for concern there?

Answer (score 1):

Not familiar with sway at all but I recently started using the `xcb` library (switched from `xlib`) and I was specifically looking for what "*code 3*" means, as a start to handle errors properly. Turns out, "code 3" means that the error is just a bad window - see `/usr/include/xcb/xproto.h`, line 1274:

```
#define XCB_WINDOW 3
```

Sway tried to perform an operation, specifically *operation 18, the change of a window property* (as seen on `op 18:0` -  as I understand it, the format is "major code:minor code"), and it failed. See `/usr/include/xcb/xproto.h` line 1932:

```
#define XCB_CHANGE_PROPERTY 18
```

As a programmer, I'd make great use of an error like that.

As for concerns, such an error is not that big of a problem but it is still an error, so it should be fixed. There are 17 different error codes so a bad window is probably not the only problem you see. The `sequence` and `value` numbers should not be of any particular use, they are not constants.

[Here](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/) is a great site with easy access to information such as this. It has a glossary of functions for the xlib library and their respective potential errors. If you want to know more, you're gonna have to dive into the `xcb` and `xlib` header files in `/usr/include/X11` and `/usr/include/xcb`.